# wordpress website crash on https

Tags: https

I have this wordpress website: Hevaweb.ir and I recently bought a ssl certificate. The problem is when the site is on http protocol, it works correctly and without any problem, but when I access it via https, all of the pictures and menus will crash!!!

I have to refresh the website 3 or 4 times to shows the full contents correctly... (and it will crash again after cleaning the chrome caches and also use ctrl+f5 keys) I've already tried these methods:

I installed the plugins to force Https on every pages (really-simple-ssl, wordpress HTTPS (ssl))
I tried to redirect all URLs from https to http manually
I checked that if the wordpress url and theme is set on Https in setting section
I manually defined Https protocol for my website on wp-config and just in case to .htaccess file
I checked the host to see if there is not problem
By the way, cloudflare is not installed either!

Comment: This is not an issue with Wordpress, but an issue either with your SSL setup or your hosting environment, and therefore not appropriate for this forum unfortunately. I would recommend contacting your host directly to see if they have any ideas for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely caused by insecure content. WordPress is serving `resources` *(images, stylesheets or scripts)* over `http` instead of `https`.

To resolve this try the following plugins:

Basic SSL setup for WordPress:
https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-ssl/

This one will find any internal link/resource request over `http` and change to `https`. 
https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/ssl-insecure-content-fixer/